# Load a select list when selecting another select

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a Flask-admin application and I have a class with a "Department" and a "Subdepartment" fields.

In the create form, I want that when a Department is selected, the Subdepartment select automatically loads all the corresponding subdepartments.

In the database, I have a "department" table and a "sub_department" table that was a foreign key "department_id".

Any clues on how I could achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow this steps

**Javascript**

1. Bind a `on change` event to your Department select .
2. If the select changes you get the value selected.
3. When you get the value, you have to send it to the server through an AJAX request.

**Flask**

4. Implement a method that reads the value and loads the associated Subdepartments.
5. Send a JSON response to the view with your Subdepartments

**Javascript**

6. In your AJAX request implement a `success` function. This function by default has as first parameter the data received from the server. Loop over them and append them to the wished select.